# Ungewöhnliche Kombination der Perfekt-Form und der Modalverben

Tags: difference, modal-verb, perfect-tense

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Different meanings / usages of Konjunktiv II in combination with the past form](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20887)*

Was ich gelernt habe:

- Modalverbe gehen nicht mit Perfekt. Ein Muttersprachler sagte mir einmal auf dem Beispielsatz „Er hat den Apfel essen können“, dass er es versteht, aber man spreche nicht so, und ich müsse es immer im Präteritum formulieren („Er konnte den Apfel essen.“).
- Im Konditional gibt es die Form: „Er hätte den Apfel essen können.“ Also zuerst kommt das Modelverb und dann konvertieren wir den Satz in Konditional + Perfekt. Niemals in der anderen Reihenfolge. (Wie es auf English geht: „He could have eaten the Apple.“)

Trotzdem finde ich Sätze in der seltenen Struktur: Subject + Modalverb + Perfekt-Form + haben. Zum Beispiel:

> Er kann den Apfel gegessen haben.

Das klingt mir irgendwie … auf Englisch:

> He could have eaten the Apple.

Also, was bedeutet diese Struktur?

Was ist die Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen?

1. > Er könnte den Apfel gegessen haben.
2. > Er hätte den Apfel essen können.

Ist (1) eigentlich richtig?

---

*Erweiterung:* Ich frage nur nach der grammatischen Korrektheit. Weil ich die Bedeutung von (1) noch nicht kenne, es ist möglich, dass es semantisch sinnlos ist.

Comment: Zur Aussage Deines Muttersprachlers: Da gibt es regionale Unterschiede - mir als Schwaben geht das Präteritum einfach schwer über die Lippen während "hat ... essen können" i.O. ist.

Comment: @Stephie =D Und gerade schreibe ich es in meiner Antwort ;)

Comment: Ich (aus Österreich) stimme Stephie und Jan zu: »Er konnte den Apfel essen« wird kein Österreicher jemals in einem normalen Alltagsgespräch sagen. »Er hat den Apfel essen können« ist hingegen vollkommen in Ordnung, und ich würde das auch genau so sagen.

Comment: Perfekt ist auch dann "Pflicht" (und daher volkommen richtig), wenn man auf absolut korrekte Zeitenfolge Wert legt: "Erst nachdem er beim Zahnarzt war, hat er den Apfel essen können" (Auch wenn es das Deutsche da nicht immer so genau nimmt...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Modalverbe gehen nicht mit Perfekt. Ein Muttersprachler sagte mir einmal auf dem Beispielsatz »Er hat den Apfel essen können«, dass er es versteht, aber man spricht nicht so, und ich muss es immer mit Präteritum nützen (»Er konnte den Apfel essen.«).

Das ist falsch. Vermutlich ist dein Muttersprachler Norddeutsch. Für mich (Bayern) ist »Er hat den Apfel essen können« das normalste der Welt. *Ich* würde die Präteritumsvariante (»Er konnte den Apfel essen«) als reine Schriftsprachenvariante klassifizieren (weiß aber, dass Norddeutsche sowas durchaus sagen).

Sowohl (1) als auch (2) sind grammatikalisch korrekt und semantisch sinnvoll. Sie sind in Nuancen leicht unterschiedlich. Bei (1) gehe ich davon aus, dass der Apfel gegessen ist, und der Schuldige gesucht wird. Bei (2) gehe ich davon aus, dass der Apfel nicht gegessen wurde, er aber in der Lage gewesen wäre.

Man kann die Formen folgendermaßen auflösen:

1. > könnte […] gegessen haben.

   In den Indikativ:

   > kann […] gegessen haben.

   Entfernen des Hilfsverbs:

   > hat […] gegessen.

   Die Hauptverbaussage ist also *hat […] gegessen;* alles Weitere modifiziert nur noch das bereits gegessene.
2. > hätte […] essen können.

   In den Indikativ:

   > hat […] essen können.

   In das Präsens:

   > kann […] essen.

   Die Hauptaussage ist also *kann essen.* Alles Weitere modifiziert die Möglichkeit des Essens.

Comment: Oder (1) er könnte ihn gegessen, oder aber auch seinem Nachbarn an den Kopf geworfen haben...

Comment: @Stephie Wirf mir das doch nicht so direkt an den Kopf D=

Comment: @Jan Er war bayrisch, das ist sicher (er hat es mir gesagt).

Comment: Diese regionalen Unterschiede werden im Atlas Alltagssprache kartiert: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f13a-e/

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Bestenfalls teilweise, weil die Karten nicht zwischen Präteritum und Perfekt (mit Ersatzinfinitiv) unterscheiden.

Answer (score 5):

Beide Formen sind Konjunktive (Möglichkeitsform). Der Unterschied ist subtil und bezieht sich darauf "was" möglich gewesen wäre. Ich versuche es mit etwas Kontext anhand von Dialogen zu verdeutlichen.

1. Irgendjemand hat einen Apfel gegessen. Und "er" könnte es gewesen sein. Bsp.: Hans: "Wo ist mein Apfel?" Bernd: "Sebastian war vorhin hier. *Er könnte den Apfel gegessen haben.*"
2. Jemand hätte den Apfel essen können, wenn er gewollt hätte. Er tat es aber nicht: Bernd. Bsp.: "Sebastian hätte gerne deinen Apfel gegessen." Hans: "*Er hätte den Apfel essen können.*"

Comment: Stimmt, beides sind Konjunktive. Im ersten Fall ist der Apfel weg im zweiten ist er noch da. Leider fehlen mir die grammatischen Begriffe um das konkret zu erklären :(

Comment: Du solltest deine Antwort entsprechend editieren, um mindestens klar zu machen, dass beide Formen Konjunktive sind; unten links gibt es einen grauen [edit]-Link. Wir verlangen ja nicht unbedingt grammatikalische Fachbegriffe, aber dort wo zwei gleiche Formen auftauchen, sollte nicht eine benannt und die andere unbenannt sein. Übrigens kannst du mit @(Name) einen User in Kommentaren pingen, mich zum Beispiel mit @Jan. Pro Kommentar geht nur ein Ping und der Postbesitzer (in diesem Fall du) wird automatisch gepingt.

Comment: @Jan ich habe mal versucht es mit Beispielen zu erlären.

Comment: Der Konjunktiv II alleine zeigt hier keine Möglichkeiten an (nur bei gewissen Modalverben (dürfen, sollen, müssen) verändert er die Bedeutung komplett in die Richtung; das trifft hier alles aber nicht zu). Der Konjunktiv II zeigt hier an, dass etwas nicht zutrifft bzw. hat gar keine Auswirkung (*könnte* kann durch *kann* ersetzt werden). Die Möglichkeit wird hier ausschließlich durch das Verb *können* ausgedrückt.